# NGINX stripping domain in Set-Cookie header

Tags: nginx, proxy, cookies

Problem: domains are stripped from the `set-cookie` header.
`httpoonly`, `expires`, and `path` are all correct.

My location block:

```
location ~* ^/path {
  proxy_pass http://nodeserver; # this is an upstream running in another container
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

- `curl foo.bar.local/path -X GET -I` -- this is hitting NGINX. `set-cookie` headers come through, but without a `domain`.
- `curl localhost/path -X GET -I` -- hitting NGINX, but under `localhost` instead of the domain, does not work.
- `curl localhost:4010/path -X GET -I` -- directly hitting the (Node) server, cookie has correct `domain`.
- Adding something like `proxy_cookie_domain ~.*$ $http_host;` doesn't seem to have any effect.
- Adding a `proxy_cookie_domain ~*.$ foo.bar.local` doesn't work.
- With `add_header Set-Cookie "foo=bar; path=/; domain=$http_host";` the domain is set correctly.
- Adding `proxy_cookie_path ~.*$ /foobar;` works as expected (cookies are rewritten to have path `/foobar`).

Rewriting the set-cookie headers in perl or lua would probably work, but that seems like the wrong solution.

Comment: Are you sure `nodeserver` sets domain in first case?

Comment: Yep. I can throw a `console.log` in there and see that it's there, or `curl` that container instead of the NGINX container and see the domain in the `Set-Cookie` header.